# Generate movies from OMDB API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, omdbapi

I am trying to view all the movies from IMDB. I am unabke to do it. THerefore I decided to use a search bar that will send the string of the name of the movie and then show the movies of that string. But it gives me error even though I generated the key.

Here is the snippet, Please help!

`axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=5657bf65'+searchText)`
What have I done wrong in the code?

Also if possible, please tell me the code to view all the movies in imdb starting from the recent without any search query.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think omdbapi has the option to display all videos, but for the search you can use it like this:

```
axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=5657bf65&s='+searchText)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are using search API but calling isn't correct.

pass &search like this

```
axios.get(http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=5657bf65&search=searchText)
```

you need to pass your searched movie name like this

```
axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=5657bf65&search=${pass searched movie name}`);
```